# Performance of merging column in excel using C# Closed XML

Tags: c#, excel, performance, performance-testing, worksheet

I'm having a List it contains 9 more property in that it contains a Child list.

For Example

```
Public Class BaseClass
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public List<ChildClass> Item3 { get; set; }
    ............
}

Public Class ChildClass
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

I Programmed to convert the collection as a Excel File with Column Grouping. In my Actual Original List I'm having more than 3000 items, each Item has a Child List with Count 4 to 6. For iterating the Collection **it takes more than 20 minutes for 1500 Collections**.

Snapshot of Sample Excel Sheet:

[image]

Kindly refer the following Sample Code it generates the Excel with Dummy Data

I'm using ClosedXML - Kindly get the reference from NuGet

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.GenerateData();
    }

    public void GenerateData()
    {
        XLWorkbook xlWorkBook = new XLWorkbook();
        IXLWorksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add("SearchResults");

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        List<TimeSpan> timeElapsedList = new List<TimeSpan>();

        Console.WriteLine("Excel Generation Started...");

        stopwatch.Start();
        int counter = 0;
        int length = 1500;
        int rowCount = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Stopwatch loopstopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            loopstopwatch.Start();
            counter++;

            #region Loop Statements Start
            int rowHeight = 5;

            int minHt = rowCount;
            int maxHt = rowCount + rowHeight - 1;

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 1).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 1).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 1";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 1).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + minHt.ToString() + ":A" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 2).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 2).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 2";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 2).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("B" + minHt.ToString() + ":B" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 3).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 3).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 3";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 3).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("C" + minHt.ToString() + ":C" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 4).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 4).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 4";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 4).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("D" + minHt.ToString() + ":D" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 5).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 5).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 5";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 5).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("E" + minHt.ToString() + ":E" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 6).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 6).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 6";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 6).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("F" + minHt.ToString() + ":F" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 7).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 7).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 7";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 7).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("G" + minHt.ToString() + ":G" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 8).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 8).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 8";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 8).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("H" + minHt.ToString() + ":H" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            for (int j = 0; j < rowHeight; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 9).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 9).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 1";
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 10).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 10).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 2";
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 11).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 11).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 3";
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 12).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 12).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 4";
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 13).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 13).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 5";
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 14).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 14).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 6";
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 15).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
                xlWorkSheet.Cell(rowCount, 15).Value = "Row " + i + " | SubRow" + j + " - Sub Item 7";

                rowCount++;
            }

            xlWorkSheet.Cell(minHt, 16).WorksheetColumn().Width = 25;
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(minHt, 16).Value = "Row " + i + " - Item 9";
            xlWorkSheet.Cell(minHt, 16).Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
            xlWorkSheet.Range("P" + minHt.ToString() + ":P" + maxHt).Column(1).Merge();

            #endregion

            loopstopwatch.Stop();
            timeElapsedList.Add(loopstopwatch.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("Iteration No: {0} - Time Taken {1}", counter, loopstopwatch.Elapsed);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Excel Construction Completed !");
        Console.WriteLine("Total Time Taken to Complete {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum Time : {0}", timeElapsedList.Min());
        Console.WriteLine("Maximum Time : {0}", timeElapsedList.Max());
    }

}
```

Kindly assist me how to optimize the Code with Column Merging in terms of Time management.

Comment: Any code that repeatedly references the workshhet inside a loop will be slow.  Many of the actions you are taking in the loop repeat the same action each iteration (eg Width).  Take as much as you can out of the loop

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes I tested the Width Property. It won't take the time and there is no difference I seen. Only thing is Cell Merging, **without Cell Merging the loop get finished in 00:00:00:42 ~**. But I need to group the data as like this. No how to overcome this performance issue.

Comment: Width was one example only.  Apply the message to other aspects of your code too. If you have identified Merging as the main time consumer, minimise the number of those operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are sure that the ranges you are merging do not intersect (which seems to be the case), you can gain much better performance by using the following `Merge` overload:

```
IXLRange Merge(bool checkIntersect)
```

and pass `false` (the parameterless `Merge` overload that you are using currently passes `true`) as `checkIntersect`. Looks like the ClosedXML implementation that checks for intersection has O(N^2) time complexity.

Shortly, replace all `.Merge()` calls with `.Merge(false)` and the execution time will be close to the one without merge.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to merge cells in 1 row only - I did workaround it with this procedure:

1. if you need to align text in merged cells to left - put the value to the **first cell**, align this cell to the **left** and keep other cells empty

   ```
   cell = row.Cell(cellNumberFirst);
   cell.SetValue("value to write");
   cell.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
   ```

2. if you need to align text in merged cells to center - put the value to the **first cell** and for range of cells to merge set **Horizontal Alignment to CenterContinuous**

```
cell = row.Cell(cellNumberFirst);
cell.SetValue("value to write");
sheet.Range(row.RowNumber(), cellNumberFirst, row.RowNumber(), cellNumberLast).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.CenterContinuous;
```

3. if you need to align text in merged cells to right - put the value to the **last cell**, align this cell to the **right** and keep other cells empty

```
cell = row.Cell(cellNumberLast);
cell.SetValue("value to write");
cell.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
```

For me it decreased SaveAs time from 2,5 hours to 15 seconds for 22500 rows and 19 columns.